# Get sunrise and sunset from openweathermap in weather app (Fatal Exception)

Tags: java, android, web-services

I am working with the weather example at this link:

< https://github.com/vyshane/rex-weather > and it's works fine.

I want to fetch the weather icon for `currentweather` but I get **Fatal Exception** error. Here is my code.

```
public class WeatherService {
    // We are implementing against version 2.5 of the Open Weather Map web service.
    private static final String WEB_SERVICE_BASE_URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5";
    private static final String API_KEY = "my-key";
    private final OpenWeatherMapWebService mWebService;

    public WeatherService() {
        RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor = new RequestInterceptor() {
            @Override
            public void intercept(RequestInterceptor.RequestFacade request) {
                request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            }
        };

        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(WEB_SERVICE_BASE_URL)
                .setRequestInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                .build();

        mWebService = restAdapter.create(OpenWeatherMapWebService.class);
    }

    private interface OpenWeatherMapWebService {
        //@GET("/weather?q=Dubai&units=metric&apikey=" + API_KEY)
        @GET("/weather?units=metric&apikey=" + API_KEY)
        Observable<CurrentWeatherDataEnvelope> fetchCurrentWeather(@Query("lon") double longitude,
                                                                   @Query("lat") double latitude);

        @GET("/forecast/daily?units=metric&cnt=7&apikey=" + API_KEY)
        // /@GET("/forecast/daily?q=Dubai&units=metric&cnt=7&apikey=" + API_KEY)
        Observable<WeatherForecastListDataEnvelope> fetchWeatherForecasts(
                @Query("lon") double longitude, @Query("lat") double latitude);
    }

    public Observable<CurrentWeather> fetchCurrentWeather(final double longitude,
                                                          final double latitude) {
        return mWebService.fetchCurrentWeather(longitude, latitude)
                .flatMap(new Func1<CurrentWeatherDataEnvelope,
                        Observable<? extends CurrentWeatherDataEnvelope>>() {

                    // Error out if the request was not successful.
                    @Override
                    public Observable<? extends CurrentWeatherDataEnvelope> call(
                            final CurrentWeatherDataEnvelope data) {
                        return data.filterWebServiceErrors();
                    }

                }).map(new Func1<CurrentWeatherDataEnvelope, CurrentWeather>() {

                    // Parse the result and build a CurrentWeather object.
                    @Override
                    public CurrentWeather call(final CurrentWeatherDataEnvelope data) {
                        /*return new CurrentWeather(data.locationName, data.timestamp,
                                data.weather.get(0).description, data.main.temp,
                                data.main.temp_min, data.main.temp_max);*/

                        return new CurrentWeather(data.locationName,data.id ,data.timestamp,
                                data.weather.get(0).description, data.main.temp,
                                data.main.temp_min, data.main.temp_max , data.sys.sunrise,
                                data.sys.sunset);
                    }
                });
    }

    public Observable<List<WeatherForecast>> fetchWeatherForecasts(final double longitude,
                                                                   final double latitude) {
        return mWebService.fetchWeatherForecasts(longitude, latitude)
                .flatMap(new Func1<WeatherForecastListDataEnvelope,
                        Observable<? extends WeatherForecastListDataEnvelope>>() {

                    // Error out if the request was not successful.
                    @Override
                    public Observable<? extends WeatherForecastListDataEnvelope> call(
                            final WeatherForecastListDataEnvelope listData) {
                        return listData.filterWebServiceErrors();
                    }

                }).map(new Func1<WeatherForecastListDataEnvelope, List<WeatherForecast>>() {

                    // Parse the result and build a list of WeatherForecast objects.
                    @Override
                    public List<WeatherForecast> call(final WeatherForecastListDataEnvelope listData) {
                        final ArrayList<WeatherForecast> weatherForecasts =
                                new ArrayList<>();

                        for (WeatherForecastListDataEnvelope.ForecastDataEnvelope data : listData.list) {
                            final WeatherForecast weatherForecast = new WeatherForecast(
                                    /*listData.city.name, data.timestamp, data.weather.get(0).description,
                                    data.temp.min, data.temp.max);*/

                            listData.city.name,data.id, data.timestamp, data.weather.get(0).description,
                                    data.temp.min, data.temp.max, data.sys.sunrise, data.sys.sunset);
                            weatherForecasts.add(weatherForecast);
                        }

                        return weatherForecasts;
                    }
                });
    }

    /**
     * Base class for results returned by the weather web service.
     */
    private class WeatherDataEnvelope {
        @SerializedName("cod")
        private int httpCode;

        class Weather {
            public String description;
        }
        public SYS sys;

        class SYS
        {public long sunrise;
            public long sunset;
        }

        /**
         * The web service always returns a HTTP header code of 200 and communicates errors
         * through a 'cod' field in the JSON payload of the response body.
         */
        public Observable filterWebServiceErrors() {
            if (httpCode == 200) {
                return Observable.just(this);
            } else {
                return Observable.error(
                        new HttpException("There was a problem fetching the weather data."));
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Data structure for current weather results returned by the web service.
     */
    private class CurrentWeatherDataEnvelope extends WeatherDataEnvelope {
        @SerializedName("name")
        public String locationName;
        @SerializedName("dt")
        public long timestamp;
        public ArrayList<Weather> weather;
        public Main main;
        public int id;

        class Main {
            public float temp;
            public float temp_min;
            public float temp_max;
        }

    }

    /**
     * Data structure for weather forecast results returned by the web service.
     */
    private class WeatherForecastListDataEnvelope extends WeatherDataEnvelope {
        public Location city;
        public ArrayList<ForecastDataEnvelope> list;

        class Location {
            public String name;
        }

        class ForecastDataEnvelope {
            @SerializedName("dt")
            public long timestamp;
            public Temperature temp;
            public ArrayList<Weather> weather;
            public int id;
            public SYS sys;
        }

        class Temperature {
            public float min;
            public float max;
        }

       class sys
        {public long sunrise;
            public long sunsit;
        }

    }
    }
```

`

And here is the error message:

```
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fatal Exception thrown on Scheduler.Worker thread.
   at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:62)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4953)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   Caused by: rx.exceptions.OnErrorFailedException: Error occurred when trying to propagate error to Observer.onError
   at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber._onError(SafeSubscriber.java:194)
   at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onError(SafeSubscriber.java:120)
   at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.pollQueue(OperatorObserveOn.java:191)
   at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber$2.call(OperatorObserveOn.java:162)
   at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4953) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771) 
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
  Caused by: rx.exceptions.CompositeException: 2 exceptions occurred. 
   at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber._onError(SafeSubscriber.java:194) 
   at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onError(SafeSubscriber.java:120) 
   at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.pollQueue(OperatorObserveOn.java:191) 
   at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber$2.call(OperatorObserveOn.java:162) 
   at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55) 
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4953) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771) 
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
  Caused by: rx.exceptions.CompositeException$CompositeExceptionCausalChain: Chain of Causes for CompositeException In Order Received =>
   at android.util.Log.getStackTraceString(Log.java:395)
   at android.util.Slog.e(Slog.java:151)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:74)
  at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
   at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
   at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:66)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4953) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771) 
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
   at mu.node.rexweather.app.Services.WeatherService$4.call(WeatherService.java:114)
   at mu.node.rexweather.app.Services.WeatherService$4.call(WeatherService.java:101)
   at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onNext(OperatorMap.java:54)
   at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emitScalar(OperatorMerge.java:477)
   at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.tryEmit(OperatorMerge.java:435)
   at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:228)
   at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:142)
   at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onNext(OperatorMap.java:54)
   at retrofit.RxSupport$2.run(RxSupport.java:56)
   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:442)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
   at retrofit.Platform$Android$2$1.run(Platform.java:142)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
  Caused by: rx.exceptions.OnErrorThrowable$OnNextValue: OnError while emitting onNext value: mu.node.rexweather.app.Services.WeatherService$WeatherForecastListDataEnvelope.class
   at rx.exceptions.Exceptions.throwOrReport(Exceptions.java:188)
   at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onNext(OperatorMap.java:56)
   at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emitScalar(OperatorMerge.java:477) 
   at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.tryEmit(OperatorMerge.java:435) 
   at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:228) 
   at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:142) 
   at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onNext(OperatorMap.java:54) 
   at retrofit.RxSupport$2.run(RxSupport.java:56) 
   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:442) 
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305) 
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137) 
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076) 
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569) 
   at retrofit.Platform$Android$2$1.run(Platform.java:142) 
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Please any help.

Comment: can you please format your code?

Comment: I edit it , now can you help me.